# Error when found api key. Error occurred during initialization of VM

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I want to find api key for using and testing my app in my device(I mean before release, i want when connect device to laptop, I want to test program and see map on device). anyway, I use this line for find md5 and sh1, but when write this in cmd, I see below error! why? How can I solve this?

I write:

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\bin>keytool -list -keytool C:\Users\my name\debug.keystore

but I am getting this error in cmd:

> Error occurred during initialization of VM
>   java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object

Please help me . Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sentence is incorrect. You should write:
 'keytool -list -v -keystore c:\users\.android\debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass android'

Please more careful

Answer (score 0):

Go to c:\eclipse folder, locate eclipse.ini file

1. add following entries

> -vm
>   C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_10\bin\javaw.exe

1. Save file
2. execute eclipse.exe

Comment: I write this line in first line of eclipse.ini and then i open again eclipse but when i write 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\bin>keytool -list -keytool C:\Users\my name\debug.keystore
' again i see that error. Why?

Comment: and another thing, i searched and i found this:Check you have C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_09\jre\lib\rt.jar. i check and i have not rt.jar in this path. my problem is this? how can i solve this problem?

Comment: If there is no rt.jar the you need to re install java again and try once

Comment: I reinstall jdk(now i have jdk1.7.0_45) and again i have not rt.jar in jdk1.7.0_45/lib folder. rt.jar is in jdk1.7.0_45/jre/lib. how can i solve this problem ?:(